# Prove the given cubic inequality

Tags: inequality

$a,b,c> 0$ prove $$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{b^3}{c+a}+\frac{c^3}{a+b}\ge\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$$

I tried AM-GM but can't reached to solution please help me

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the right hand side from the left hand side and showing it's non-negative ?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914634/is-my-method-for-proving-certain-types-of-multivariable-inequalities-correct, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791161/question-from-a-moscow-summer-camp

Answer (score 3):

Using the Angel form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\displaystyle \sum_{cyclic}\dfrac{a^3}{b+c} = \displaystyle \sum_{cyclic}\dfrac{(a^2)^2}{ab+ac}\ge \dfrac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{2(ab+bc+ca)}\ge \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$ since $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca$ which is clear.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If you want to use AM-GM,
$$\frac{a^3}{b+c}+\frac{a(b+c)}4\ge a^2$$

Add three such inequalities to sum and then use the rearrangement $ab+bc+ca\le a^2+b^2+c^2$.