# Question from a Moscow summer camp

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

Prove that, given $a,b,c > 0$ and $n$ a positive integer,

$$\frac{a^n}{b+c}+\frac{b^n}{a+c}+\frac{c^n}{a+b} \geq \frac{a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+c^{n-1}}{2}\ .$$

I've tried every rathole for hours on this little fellow... It seems simple, and can be intuited, but it‘s devilish to solve. A good first step (I don't want to give out my four or five approaches for fear of distracting), I think, is to let $a \geq b \geq c$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi! Please read [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can properly typeset mathematical expressions in the future.

Comment: Let $a\ge b\ge c$ then use Chebyshev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^n}{b+c}-\frac{a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+c^{n-1}}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^n}{b+c}-\frac{a^{n-1}}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{n-1}(a-b-(c-a))}{2(b+c)}=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{a^{n-1}}{2(b+c)}-\frac{b^{n-1}}{2(c+a)}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)(c(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})+a^n-b^n)}{2(a+c)(b+c)}\geq0$$
because $$(a-b)(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})\geq0$$ and
$$(a-b)(a^n-b^n)\geq0.$$